# What's the best way to store messages in route in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm working on a message pipeline in Apache Camel and could use some input on the design. Basically, messages are coming into the pipe and need to get stored somewhere before a human triggered process manually approves/rejects each message. I want something that is resilient so that even if the system goes down the messages wouldn't be lost.

I was thinking of converting each message into a short text file and having camel consume that text file. But this way seem pretty clunky. Does anyone know of a better way of doing it?'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [JMS/ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) for reliable asynchronous messaging...integrates easily with Camel and other applications that need to produce/consume message based data (text, xml, serialized, etc)